# реферальная система и баллы python telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

Необходимо приглашать друзей к боту по реф ссылкам, и при этом Пользователь который пригласил, получает баллы. Дайте наводку, как можно организовать этот процесс. И если имеется, дайте код для примера. Спасибо!

Comment: А в телеграмме есть друзья?..

Comment: Максимум, что вы можете сделать, это использовать deep links https://core.telegram.org/api/links